# How do I add 2 weeks to a Date in java?

Tags: java, datetime

I am getting a Date from the object at the point of instantiation, and for the sake of outputting I need to add 2 weeks to that date. I am wondering how I would go about adding to it and also whether or not my syntax is correct currently.

Current Java:

```
private final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
private Date dateOfOrder;

private void setDateOfOrder()
{
    //Get current date time with Date()
    dateOfOrder = new Date();      
}

public Date getDateOfOrder()
{
    return dateOfOrder;
}
```

Is this syntax correct? Also, I want to make a getter that returns an estimated shipping date, which is 14 days after the date of order, I'm not sure how to add and subtract from the current date.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use Calendar and set the current time then user the add method of the calendar

try this:

```
int noOfDays = 14; //i.e two weeks
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dateOfOrder);            
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, noOfDays);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of a calendar class that could be manipulated like this!!

Comment: Would daysToAdd be an integer? or some other data type?

Comment: Yep! If it works I will be sure to do that!

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs yes its an integer type.

Answer (score 16):

I will show you how we can do it in Java 8. Here you go:

```
public class DemoDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("Current date: " + today);

        //add 2 week to the current date
        LocalDate next2Week = today.plus(2, ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
        System.out.println("Next week: " + next2Week);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Current date: 2016-08-15
Next week: 2016-08-29
```

Java 8 rocks !!

Answer (score 8):

Use Calendar

```
    Date date = ...
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 2);
    date = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this to add two weeks.

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis() + 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
Date newDate = new Date(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

if pass 14 to this addDate method it will add 14 to the current date and return

```
public String addDate(int days) throws Exception {
    final DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, addDays); // Adding 5 days
    return dateFormat1.format(c.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Joda-Time library will be easier and will handle Daylight Saving Time, other anomalies, and time zones.

```
java.util.Date date = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Denver" ) ).plusWeeks( 2 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on java 8 you can use new date time api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusWeeks-long-

if you are on java 7 or more old version of java you should use old api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-